# What are refereed and non-refereed journals?

Tags: publications, journals, conference, peer-review

What does it mean by publication in refereed and non-refereed journals? Are these terms applicable to conference papers too? Is there any relationship with peer-review?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refereed_journal

Comment: That Wikipedia link does not provide the answer directly.

Comment: That wikipedia link redirects to Peer-review, so I guess it directly answers the relation with peer-review ;)

Comment: Refereeing is the same as scholarly peer review. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refereed_journal#Scholarly_peer_review).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your original question, "referred journal" is a [Freudian slip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudian_slip), perhaps on your part.

Refereed journals/conferences are the ones where the published papers have been peer-reviewed.